# Webresponce Denial of Service

Tags: asp.net, web-services, security

I am using this code:-

```
    WebRequest webrequest = WebRequest.Create("myurl");
    webrequest.Method = "GET";
    webrequest.ContentType = "application/json";
    webrequest.ContentLength = 0;
    using (WebResponse jsonResponse = webrequest.GetResponse())
     {
      using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(jsonResponse.GetResponseStream()))
       {
           result = reader.ReadToEnd();                            
       }
    }
```

if an attacker inject large amount of data my system will hang/crass on this line `result = reader.ReadToEnd();` as this will take large amount of memory & time.

My question is is there anyway to protect this code from attacker.

Comment: It's not really "an attack" when *your code* is performing the request...

Comment: @David sorry if i am wrong, while requesting if an attacker inject large amount of data, `reader.ReadToEnd(); ` will take to much time and it may give `OutOfMemoryException`

Comment: If you're worried that the stream might be too long then read it in chunks rather than reading the whole thing at once.  My point earlier is that nobody is *attacking* your application.  *Your application* is requesting data.  There's no denial of service, no security violation, no attack of any kind.  You're simply requesting data from a server.  If you suspect that there may be *a lot* of data in the response then use the response stream as a stream rather than loading the whole response into memory.